# Интересное поведение kotlinx

Tags: android, kotlin

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, подключил библиотеку, в которой есть некие вьюшки с определенными id'шками. И в main проекте при обращении к этому определенному view не взначай прописал тот же id и для свой view.
После этого `kotlinx` вместо того чтобы обращаться в классе к моей id моего проекта, обратился вплоть до id подключенной библиотеки.

Как можно избежать подобных ситуаций?
Пока как вариант это переименование id в main или библиотеки, но так как это  порой не явно всплывает, то хотелось бы как то по другому обойти. Возможно кто то сталкивался уже с чем-то подобным.

**UPD**:

Хочу заметить что импорт не меняется, к примеру:

`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dialog_immediate_categorization.*`

Где в самой разметке:

```
<com.mandarine.android.common.views.TitleSwitchView
    android:id="@+id/switchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleText="@string/v2_mobile_categories_assign_all_enable" />
```

Где как видно что: `com.mandarine.android.common` это в моём случае элемент подключенной библиотеки в которой для класса `TitleSwitchView` выделена разметка состоящая из `TextView` и `SwitchView` в котором так раз таки и указан id `switchView`.
И уже в моём классе он обращается не к `switchView` типа `TitleSwitchView` а к id `switchView` типа `SwitchView`.

Comment: Что-то странное. Кусочек кода покажите.

Comment: @Эникейщик обновил вопрос, так думаю будет более понятно.

Comment: Кусочек кода, в котором проявляется некорректное обращение. Сейчас совершенно непонятно, кто к кому и в каком контексте некорректно обращается. `kotlinx` - это часть пути пакета котлиновских библиотек - как он в принципе может куда-то обращаться - вопрос.

Comment: Значит у вас в одном xml файле два UI элемента с id `switchView`. Не делайте так и все будет Ок.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja по сути это не один `xml`, здесь больше идёт речь о во вложенных `view`.

Comment: `dialog_immediate_categorization.xml` пройдитесь поиском по `switchView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скройте ресурсы библиотеки. Хороший ответ в офф документации    https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#PrivateResources

Answer (score 1):

Уу, вот это вопрос! Затрагивает давно известную тему доступности ресурса по всему коду приложения, и как следстве опасность коллизии имен.
Механизм поиска обекта в КотлинИкс подразумевает скоуп всего дерева элементов. Обойти данную проблему можно отказом от КотлинИкс. Главное не прибегать к решению в котором используются более сложные имена для обьектов. Автор вопроса молодец!